# apt-get and dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

I thought apt-get was a package manager that installs all dependencies by default when it installs an application. But when I tried installing gcc-4.7, I get this:

```
 sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.7 : Depends: cpp-4.7 (= 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgcc-4.7-dev (= 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dev : Depends: libgcc-4.7-dev (= 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) but it is not going to be installed
```

Why didnt it install the "unmet dependencies"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility that if they were installed they would conflict with something else. Or, maybe something is messed up in your software configuration. What I would do first is use the `apt-get -f install` command like the prompt tells you to, and then try installing again.

If that doesn't work try using `aptitude` to install gcc. Aptitude usually is able to fix problems automatically when apt-get can't. (As you have just found out) Just install it using:

```
# apt-get install aptitude
```

And then just use it like you would use apt-get:

```
# aptitude install gcc-4.7
```

You may also want to use aptitude to update your packages and upgrade if the previous command doesn't work:

```
# aptitude update
# aptitude upgrade
```